# JPA problem hope JPA specialist can help me

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, persistence

I want to build a statement

```
SELECT * FROM EVENT WHERE USER_APPLY LIKE 'EVENT_DETAIL.USERNAME';
```

The upper one is the SQL code that I want
But now I want to turn that SQL code to JPA

Anyone can help me to convert it??

PS the `USERNAME` is under the `EVENT_DETAIL` Class

All my variable was uppercase

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query
Check this link.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
@Query("Select ed from EVENT_DETAIL ed  where ed.USERNAME like :username")
String findEventByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
```